# HLS Streaming on IPad with IOS 7 / 8 causes 10 seconds freezed frame - no clue why

Tags: ipad, streaming, http-live-streaming, wowza, x264

We have a problem with HLS h.264 mp4 on IPad devices using HLS streaming on IOS 7 and 8:

The first 9-15 seconds (the length of the first TS segment) only shows the first key frame (IDR) of the second TS segment, while the sound plays normally. When the second segment begins to play, the video continues as it should.

HLS segmenter is a wowza with 10 seconds segment length. The encoding software we use is TMPG, latest version (uses x264). The funny thing is, that handbrake, xmedia recode, adobe me deliver videos which work. I am aware of the fact, that this hints to a bug within our encoding software, but if someone already had that problem with another software / segmenter combination and fixed it, I would like to know what the source of the problem was.

What we already tried:

- changing almost every setting so that it sticks as close as possible to apple's recommendations
- changing GOP structure, GOP length, encoding parameters which influence efficiency of encoding
- analysis of the TS segments created by wowza, they are fine and begin all with keyframes
- contact TMPG/Apple/Wowza support

So, did anyone stumble upon this problem before? Has anyone solved it?

EDIT:

It seems that TMPGEnc uses a defective x264 implementation. The mediastreamvalidator tool from Apple returned an error stating that our TS segment "does not contain any IDR access unit with a SPS and a PPS" - which it does actually, but obviously in the wrong places if that somehow matters.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever tool you use for segmenting is not ensuring that the segment begins with an SPS+PPS+IDR. this could be an issue with your encoder or your segmenter. Basically, decoding can nor begin until all three of these thing are encountered in the player. Try using mediafilessegmenter and mediastreamvarifier from apple to analyze the problem.

Comment: The extracted segments actually both contain SPS+PPS just before I-Slices. Ich checked this using Elecard Stream Analyzer. There is one difference though: The working TS segment has another order of those elements: 

AUD;SPS;PPS;SEI (Buffering Period);SEI(Picture Timing);I-Slice
 
whereas the non-working TS has the order:

SPS;PPS;AUD;SEI(Buffering Period);TP;TP;TP;TP;SEI(Picture Timing);I-Slice

Does this cause any trouble? Besides, the working segment also contains more I-Slices with each SPS + PPS.

Comment: Sorry for double postings: Thank you for the advice with both tools. We will try them asap.